# How to autoplay brightcove video playlist in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, brightcove

I am trying to `autoplay` a `videoplay` list in `brightcove`, it works perfectly in `flash` but not in `HTML5`.

Using this reference:

http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/samples/autoplay-with-captions.html

I was able to `autoplay` a single video in `HTML5`, but it doesn't work for a video playlist.

Answer (score 1):

There is an 'Auto Advance to Next Video' setting on the player, you might want to look into.

You can also play around with the javascript callback if you are unable to make any changes to the player settings.

```
if (typeof videojs != 'undefined' ) {
  videojs("my_player").ready(function () {

    my_player.on("loadedmetadata",function(){
      ...
      my_player.play();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that you will need.

```
<video controls autoplay      preload="auto" ...>
```

good luck with that!

Comment: I've already tried this but the issue is that the video tag is present in the iframe coming generated on Brightcove servers and i cant access this video tag using javascript because of the cross origin request block issues